# WordPress Hero Slider Issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress

[Screen Shot!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40cdJ.png)
Hi desperate for a bit of help here!!!!

http://www.cambrianvacation.co.uk/4penny/book

I have a few Hero Sliders on this site, the WordPress plugin. 1 load out of every ten the slider is loading very small, especially if you return to the page via the back button.

The developers of the plugin aren't really offering a solution. I don't think it is a conflict with another JS plugin. As I have jQuery UI added later and no other JS being called.

Help appreciated!!

Ant

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community.  At the very least, try to include a [mcve] to your question. Without it, it is nearly impossible to know *exactly* where the issue lies.

Comment: Ok that's resolved, it only seems to be happening via the back button now. I think it is only happening when document.ready isn't called. When you hit the back button does that bypass or is that bypassing document.ready???

Comment: it does not bypass `document.ready`, no but it could be cached (the page, files, etc.)

Comment: are you sure the small images are the correct size? (as opposed to being actually, well, small)

Comment: Image size is fine across devices.

Comment: Need to disable the bfcache then???

Comment: if you are using a plugin, you could prolly just clear the server-side cache and see if it works - also, the call to get the Arial font is failing.. might want to look into it

Comment: I think it's an issue with the Plugin WordPress Hero Slider, the issue is repeating on normal page load. I'm abandoning this plugin as no solution has been offered by the developers.